# docker cache memory increasing all the time

Tags: docker, puppeteer

#### Steps to reproduce

**Tell us about your environment:**

- Puppeteer version:1.6.1
- Platform / OS version: linux
- URLs (if applicable):
- Node.js version: 8

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

deployed docker in linux. We make a health check of screenshot per minutes. The problem is that  the docker cache memory is increasing all the time even we disable nearly all the cache, although rss did not increase. 
this is part of code below:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage','--media-cache-size=1','--disk-cache-size=1','--disable-application-cache','--disable-session-storage','--user-data-dir=/dev/null']})
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
```

But if we execute  `"# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"` to clear `dentries` and `inodes` the cache memory will be decreasing rapidly.  But we have disabled chrome to write cache. So we don't know what makes cache memory grow.

Comment: What is in the Dockerfile? Can you share it?

Comment: yes. see below docker file

Comment: The thing is, you do not add that as an answer, you should edit your question and add to that.

Comment: From what I see, maybe you are generating a huge log file somewhere. And many other possible issues, can you edit your question and add a sample github link?

Comment: here is my git link: https://github.com/CodeGerm/puppeteer-renderer

Comment: What is the concern with a growing cache? Linux will cache disk reads in memory as long as you have unused RAM to reduce the load on the disk and increase performance.

Comment: We set a 1G docker memory limit. When the docker memory reaches 1G, we will kill it. So usually, the docker memory will increase 80m one hour.   And it usually take 12 hours to get 1g. The point is it's increasing all the time. We can only manually execute # sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches to make the memory fall down

Comment: If you aren't you should be closing chrome after every session and starting a new chrome instance for each subsequent task. This can be somewhat hard to do, but doing it right will help tremendously with issues like this. I maintain an image that provides a webservice around chrome found here: https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless

Comment: I just did what you said. restart the chrome will decrease chrome's res. But it do nothing about the disk cache

Answer (score 0):

I think BMitch is right. linux will grow the disk cache from unused ram. And docker.stats will include disk cache. The reason why docker.stats is always growing is the disk cache is growing. And ec2 will monitor the docker.stats. I think this is ec2's problem. Thx guys.